# Macro issues in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement some code that is working for other people. I am using Visual Studio 2013, but I believe they're using a different compiler. Everything in the code is working properly expect a handful of macros.

One example:

```
#ifndef SAFE_DELETE
#define SAFE_DELETE(x) /
    if (x != NULL)        /
    {                    /
    delete x;     /
    x = NULL;         /
}
#endif
```

Here I get the error `expected a declaration`, or `error C2059: syntax error : 'if'`

Not surprisingly, I get an error when trying to use it:

```
SAFE_DELETE(*it); // "expected an expression"
```

The namespace where I define this macro is shared with the rest of my application, and the macro isn't used anywhere else. There also isn't any other syntax errors. Commenting out the include and `SAFE_DELETE(*it);` produces code that will compile. Additionally, replacing the macro call with the code from the macro also works.

I tried to re-define the function as follows:

```
#ifndef SAFE_DELETE
#define SAFE_DELETE(x) /
    x = NULL;         /
#endif
```

This produces the error `Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`. That leads me to believe that somehow this isn't being called in a class, yet it very clearly is.

What could be causing this issue? Additionally, how is it possible that this compiled for someone else?

Comment: those macros will cause problems in the future... always use a `do..while` block when doing those kind of macros...

Comment: @self Rest assured, those macros will be replaced once everything is ported properly.

Comment: The check for null is not needed. And for future reference for people who want this, an equivalent macro-less version would look like `template<typename T> void safeDelete(T *&x) {delete x; x = NULL;}`. In C++11, that would be `nullptr`, but really, the manual `delete` in the first place smells.

Comment: The check for null is not needed, and the assignment of null doesn't help with making deletes safer, it only reduces the contexts where this macro can be used (which however is a good thing, since zero usage of it would be ideal). Use collections and smart pointers to manage memory. Note that assignment of null can **hide bugs**, which is not a good thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a backslash (`\`) to continue a line, not a forward slash (`/`).

Comment: That makes sense, and it is indeed working now. Still, I can't think of how this could compile for someone else.

Comment: Ah, I think I found the issue. There was this compile script that ran a replace-all \ to / that one of our team members wrote to make the windows people play nice with the linux people. Removing that fixed the issue. Time to go teach someone what the word "test" means before pushing to our main branch :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has not been mentioned here: When faced with anomalous behavior involving macros, look at the preprocessor output immediately to see the code that the compiler is actually compiling. (e.g. use "cc -E".) This would have made the forward slash issue obvious. Then find a system where it is successfully compiling and do the same thing. That will show the slashes are different and from there you can find what is changing the source code text. (And if it is common practice to do things like change *all* '/' characters to '\' everywhere in C++ source files, I would also suggest finding another job or project.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware that this was possible. I don't usually deal with macros, so my experience with the preprocessor is "it just works".